# I can't checkout a single file from a remote repository using JGit

Tags: git, jgit

I want to checkout a single file from my git remote repository using JGit. The code I am using is this:

```
CheckoutCommand checkoutCommand=git.checkout();
checkoutCommand.addPath("file1.txt");
try {
    checkoutCommand.call();
} catch (GitAPIException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The git object is initialized correctly because when I use it to create a pull command with `git.pull()` it works. When I run the above code it seems that it works because it doesn't enter the `catch` block, but when I open the working area of my local repository I don't see the `file1.txt` file.

P.S.
Now I have tried to add the line `checkoutCommand.setName("master");` but it still downloads nothing.

Comment: There is no branch specified (e.g. using `setName`). Which branch you are going to check out?  Does that branch contain `file1.txt`?

Comment: The master branch, yes the file is present in my remote repository.

Comment: You need to fetch changes from the remote repository before you can checkout them. Checkout considers only commits in the local repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is this one:

```
CheckoutCommand checkoutCommand=git.checkout();
checkoutCommand.setName("origin/master");
checkoutCommand.addPath("file1.txt");
try {
    checkoutCommand.call();
} catch (GitAPIException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Some suggest executing a `fetch` before the `checkout`, but in order to download `file1.txt` it hasn't been necessary.
Basically I had to set the name as `origin/master`.